# Remove (splice) value from one scope/ng-options, while maintaining values in another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a dropdown list populated by one scope and the same list displayed using another scope. When I select something from the dropdown I want to hide/remove it from the display list, but keep the full list in the dropdown.

```
I have a JS fiddle started: https://jsfiddle.net/mfzbk8nv/6/
```

Fiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfzbk8nv/6/)

Right now what's happening is that it removed the first letter in the display list and not the one I want to remove. Second, it removes from both the dropdown and the displaylist.

Any help appreciated!

My HTML:

```
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="mySel" ng-options="i for i in list2" ng-change="removeIt(mySel)" ></select>

    <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list1">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    $scope.list1 = arr;
    $scope.list2 = arr;

    $scope.removeIt = function(i){    
        $scope.list1.splice(i,1)        
    }    
})
```

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mfzbk8nv/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-options` does not have an `$index`, that's only within `ng-repeat`

You have to create your own way of indexing the ng-options, by grouping things and creating your own.

```
<select ng-model="mySel" 
    ng-options="index as mySel for (index, mySel) in list2"
    ng-change="removeIt(mySel)" />
```

Now `mySel` will be this `index` that's created no each iteration.

**[jsFiddle Updated Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/wn919o04/)**

Comment: What if I wanted to remove it, not by index, but by actual text selected?

Comment: You'd have to just make a `for()` loop, compare the text to each item in the array, and when it matches, delete that index (from the for loop) `arr.splice(i, 1)` from your array. @crowsfeet

Answer (score 0):

Both list1 and list2 are reference the same array arr. So when you change one of them,you change the other one. 
Try to duplicate it

```
var dup_array = original_array.slice
```